# Laurent series find the coeficients

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Suppose

$$z\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}= \sum_{-\infty}^{n} a_nz^n $$
the  laurent series of $f(z)= z\frac{cosz}{sinz} $ on the ring π<|z|<2π.Find the $a_n$.

Now i know $a_n= \frac{1}{2πi}  \int\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$ so for $$n=0$$i plug in the $f$ and i try to use the residues theorem but i dont know the order of the anomalies at 0,π,-π
 and i dont know what formula to use to calculate the residues.I know that to find out what order the anomalies are i have to calculate the limit $\frac{cosz}{sinz}$ but it is a complex limit  1/0 is infinite in complex numbers. so that means i have to expand the laurent series for  that function and cant use a residues formula  which looks like the  initial task. im confused.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $\;z^{\color{red}n}\;$ there...?

Comment: @DonAntonio where? ooh yeah

Comment: Do you want *the whole* Laurent development or just enough to find out the residue of the formula at $\;z=\pi\;$ ?

Comment: i want to find $a_n$  for negative $n <= 0$ @DonAntonio

Comment: Then there you go: look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the series around $\;z=\pi\;$ , which is a pole of the function:

$$z\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=z\frac{\cos(z-\pi)}{\sin(z-\pi)}=\left[(z-\pi)+\pi\right]\frac{1-\frac{(z-\pi)^2}{2}+\mathcal O((z-\pi)^4)}{(z-\pi)\left(1-\frac{(z-\pi)^2}{6}+\mathcal O((z-\pi)^4)\right)}=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac{\left[(z-\pi)+\pi\right]}{z-\pi}\left(1-\frac{(z-\pi)^2}{2}+\mathcal O((z-\pi)^4)\right)\left(1+\frac{(z-\pi)^2}6+\mathcal O((z-\pi)^4)\right)=$$$${}$$

$$=\frac\pi{z-\pi}+\ldots$$

and there's your residue.

Comment: i want to find the series on the whole ring .

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis I've no idea what that means, and above you told you want the coefficients with negative index, and there you have them.